# A class has a field/property the same as its own type?

Tags: c#

I'm confused about this statement:

```
ctrlID.Font.Size = FontUnit.Small;
```

but FontUnit is a struct under System.Web.UI.WebControls

```
public struct FontUnit
{
   ...
   public static readonly FontUnit Small;
   ...
}
```

as a struct is a class, so how can we have a class A that has its self as a object like:

```
public class A{
   public A a;
}
```

isn't it like creating an endless chain of objects which would require infinite memory?

Comment: `as a struct is a class` How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: `so how can we have a class A that has its self as a object like:` It doesn't have itself as an object. It has a **field** that is of the same **type**. Imagine a `Person` with a `Father` field. That is perfectly legitimate. It won't be an endless chain, necessarily, since the `a` field is nullable. It _could_ be an endless chain if `A`'s constructor sets the `a` field (which will call the constructor again, which will set the field again, etc etc).

Comment: A great example of an endless chain is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54247273/stackoverflow-when-creating-object .

Answer (score 2):

The property is [static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static), so it's a member of the Type, and not of the object instance. You do not need to construct the `Small` static property to create a `FontUnit` object.

Consider this:

```
public class Foo 
{
    public static Foo Default {get;}
    static Foo() 
    {
         Default = new Foo();
    }
}
```

`Default` is only constructed once, at an unknown time before it is used.

If it's not static, you can get into the behavior you expected.

```
public class Foo 
{
    public Foo Default {get; private set;}
    public Foo() 
    {
        Default = new Foo();
    }
}
```

This will cause an overflow, as the property will keep instantiating a new `Foo`, which will make a new `Foo`, and so on.

So long as you're careful not to instantiate a type with the same constructor you are currently instantiating a type in there shouldn't be any issue with a type having member of it's own type.